# When is an rvalue evaluated?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, temporary, rvalue

So I understand that `s2` binds to the expression `s1 + s1`, but is this evaluated at the time `s2` is assigned or is it lazy and evaluated when `s2 += "Test";` is called? And also would `s2` hold memory for a temporary string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "Test";
    std::string&& s2 = s1 + s1;
    s2 += "Test";
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `s2` binds to the expression `s1 + s1`, but is this evaluated at the time `s2` is assigned

Yes.

> And also would `s2` hold memory for a temporary string?

Precisely, `s2` is bound to a temporary `std::string`.

`s1 + s1` will produce a temporary `std::string`, which will be bound to the reference `s2` (and its lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the reference). Then `s2 += "Test";`, performs `operator+=()` on `s2`, i.e. the temporary `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It seems that if `s2` was just another `std::string`, the results will be the same, but would the resulting binaries be any different?

Comment: @BradyDean Yes the result is the same. It's hard to say about the result binaries; Anyway I tried it [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and it gave the same assembly.

Comment: Note that this changes in C++17 in a way that makes zero observable difference in this case.

Comment: @Yakk You mean temporary materialization?

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes.  `s1+s2` is a prvalue, which is then materialized into a temporary.  Very, very slight difference.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions are always evaluated at the point the program reaches them. The result of an expression is always a value (or void).

Values have a type, and expressions have a value category, which combine to choose which overload of an overload set is used, at any particular use.

In your case, `string operator+(...)` results in a string value, with the category pr-value (which is a type of rvalue). It is then immediately bound to a string&&, so it's lifetime is extended to that of the reference.

If you had instead assigned it to a plain string, `string& string::operator=(string&&)` would have been chosen over any other overloads of that operator. Note that since c++11 the compiler is allowed (and from c++17 required) to materialize the value directly inside the target object. This process is known as copy/move elision or (N)RVO, for (Named) Return Value Optimisation.

Comment: @Yakk Which things particularly? To my knowledge the only change is that the move construction is elided, and that isn't observably different to c++14 for string

Comment: Sorry, I swore I saw the word "object" where it wasn't supposed to be, but I don't see it now, so I must have been wrong.